# Error en la declaración de las variables x e y

Tags: c++

Al momento de compilar me manda un error en las variables de x e y; según yo todo está bien.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <list>
    using namespace std;
    #define ARRIBA 72
    #define IZQUIERDA 75
    #define DERECHA 77
    #define ABAJO 80
    
    void fflush_in() {
     int ch;
     while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n') {}
    }
    
    void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
     //HANDLE es el nombre que recibe la consola, i l'he ponemos el nombre de que queramos
     //en este caso hCon que es el que se pone por defecto.
     HANDLE hCon;
     //Coje el identificador de la ventana (GetStdHandle)
     hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     //Creamos las cordenadas.
     COORD dwPos;
     dwPos.X = x;
     dwPos.Y = y;
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, dwPos);
    }
    void ocultarCursor() {
     HANDLE hCon;
     hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
     cci.dwSize = 2;
     cci.bVisible = FALSE;
     SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);
    }
    void pintarLimites() {
     for (int i = 2; i < 78; i++) {
      gotoxy(i, 3); printf("%c", 205);
      gotoxy(i, 33); printf("%c", 205);
     }
     for (int i = 4; i < 33; i++) {
      gotoxy(2, i); printf("%c", 186);
      gotoxy(77, i); printf("%c", 186);
     }
     gotoxy(2, 3); printf("%c", 201);
     gotoxy(2, 33); printf("%c", 200);
     gotoxy(77, 3); printf("%c", 187);
     gotoxy(77, 33); printf("%c", 188);
    }
    
    class NAVE {
     int x, y;
     int corazones;
     int vidas;
    public:
     NAVE(int  _x, int _y, int _corazones, int _vidas) : x(_x), y(_y), corazones(_corazones), vidas(_vidas) {}
     int X() { return x; }
     int Y() { return y; }
     int VID() { return vidas; }
     void pCorazon() { corazones--; }
     void gCorazon() { if (corazones < 3)corazones++; }
     void pintar();
     void borrar();
     void mover();
     void pintarCorazones();
     void morir();
    };
    class AST {
     int x, y;
    public:
     AST(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
     void pintar();
     void mover();
     void choque(class NAVE &N);
     void borrar();
     int X() { return x; }
     int Y() { return y; }
    };
    class VIDA {
     int x, y;
    public:
     VIDA(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
     void pintar();
     void mover();
     void choque(class NAVE &N);
     void borrar();
    };
    class BALA {
     int x, y;
    public:
     BALA(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {};
     int X() { return x; }
     int Y() { return y; }
     void mover();
     bool fuera();
    };
    /*
    ALTERNATIVA a : x(_x), y(_y) {}
    NAVE::NAVE(int _x, int _y) {
     x = _x;
     y = _y;
    }*/
    void NAVE::pintar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf("  %c", 30);
     gotoxy(x, y + 1); printf(" %c%c%c", 40, 207, 41);
     gotoxy(x, y + 2); printf("%c%c %c%c", 30, 190, 190, 30);
     system("color 7");
    }
    
    void NAVE::borrar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf("     ");
     gotoxy(x, y+1); printf("     ");
     gotoxy(x, y+2); printf("     ");
    }
    
    void NAVE::mover() {
    
     if (kbhit()) {
      char tecla = getch();
      borrar();
      if (tecla == IZQUIERDA && x > 3) x--;
      if (tecla == DERECHA && x+6 < 77) x++;
      if (tecla == ARRIBA && y > 4) y--;
      if (tecla == ABAJO && y + 3 < 33) y++;
      pintar();
      pintarCorazones();
     }
    }
    void NAVE::pintarCorazones() {
    
     gotoxy(50, 2); printf("VIDAS %d", vidas);
     gotoxy(64, 2); printf("Salud");
     gotoxy(70, 2); printf("      ");
     for (int i = 0; i < corazones; i++) {
      gotoxy(70 + i, 2); printf("%c\r",03);
     }
    }
    void NAVE::morir() {
     if (corazones == 0) {
      borrar();
      gotoxy(x, y);   printf("  *  ");
      gotoxy(x, y + 1); printf("** **");
      gotoxy(x, y + 2); printf("  *  ");
      Sleep(200);
      borrar();
      gotoxy(x, y);   printf("* * *");
      gotoxy(x, y + 1); printf(" * ");
      gotoxy(x, y + 2); printf("* * *");
      Sleep(200);
      borrar();
      vidas--;
      corazones = 3;
      pintarCorazones();
      pintar();
     }
    
    
    
    
    }
    void AST::pintar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf("%c", 'o');
    }
    void AST::mover() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf(" ");
     y++;
     if (y > 32) {
      x = rand() % 71 + 4;
      y = 4;
     }
     pintar();
    }
    void AST::choque(class NAVE &N) {
     if (x >= N.X() && x < N.X() + 6 && y >= N.Y() && y <= N.Y() + 2) {
      N.pCorazon();
      borrar();
      N.pintar();
      N.pintarCorazones();
      x = rand() % 71 + 4;
      y = 4;
     }
    }
    
    void AST::borrar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf(" ");
    }
    
    void VIDA::pintar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf("%c", 3);
    }
    void VIDA::mover() {
     gotoxy(x, y);printf(" ");
     y++;
     if (y > 32) {
      x = rand() % 71 + 4;
      y = 4;
     }
     pintar();
    }
    void VIDA::choque(class NAVE &N) {
     if (x >= N.X() && x < N.X() + 6 && y >= N.Y() && y <= N.Y() + 2) {
      N.gCorazon();
      N.pintarCorazones();
      borrar();
      N.pintar();
      x = rand() % 71 + 4;
      y = 4;
     }
    }
    void VIDA::borrar() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf(" ");
    }
    void BALA::mover() {
     gotoxy(x, y); printf(" ");
     y--;
     gotoxy(x, y); printf("*");
    }
    bool BALA::fuera() {
     if (y == 4) {
      return true;
     }
     else {
      return false;
     }
    }
    int main() {
    
     char tecla;
     do
     {
      ocultarCursor();
      pintarLimites();
      list<AST*> A;
      list<AST*>::iterator itA;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       A.push_back(new AST(rand() % 75 + 3, rand() % 5 + 4));
      }
      NAVE N(15, 25, 3, 3);
      VIDA vit(15, 8);
      list<BALA*> B;
      list<BALA*>::iterator it;
      N.pintar();
      int puntos = 0;
      bool game_over = false;
      while (!game_over) {
       gotoxy(4, 2); printf("PUNTOS %d", puntos);
       if (kbhit()) {
        char tecla = getch();
        if (tecla == 'a') {
         B.push_back(new BALA(N.X() + 2, N.Y() - 1));
        }
       }
       for (it = B.begin(); it != B.end();) {
        (*it)->mover();
        if ((*it)->fuera()) {
         gotoxy((*it)>X(), (*it)>Y()); printf(" ");
         delete(*it);
         it = B.erase(it);
        }
        else { it++; }
       }
       N.mover();
       vit.mover(); vit.choque(N);
       for (itA = A.begin(); itA != A.end(); itA++) {
        (*itA)->mover();
        (*itA)->choque(N);
       }
       for (itA = A.begin(); itA != A.end(); itA++) {
        for (it = B.begin(); it != B.end();) {
         if ((*itA)>X() == (*it)>X() && ((*itA)>Y() + 1 == (*it)>Y() || (*itA)>Y() == (*it)>Y())) {
          gotoxy((*it)>X(), (*it)>Y());printf(" ");
          delete (*it);
          it = B.erase(it);
          A.push_back(new AST(rand() % 74 + 3, 4));
          gotoxy((*itA)>X(), (*itA)>Y());printf(" ");
          delete (*itA);
          itA = A.erase(itA);
          puntos = puntos + 5;
         }
         else { it++; }
    
        }
       }
       if (N.VID() < 0)
       {
        game_over = true;
       }
       N.morir();
       Sleep(60);
      }
      gotoxy(4, 35); printf("\nGAME OVER\n");
      printf("JUGAR DE 9? [S/N]\n");
      do {
       scanf("%c", &tecla);
       fflush_in();
       tecla = towlower(tecla);
       if (tecla != 's' && tecla != 'n') {
        printf("Solo [S/N]");
       }
      } while (tecla != 's' && tecla != 'n');
      system("cls");
     } while (tecla != 'n');
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: En principio no hay ningún problema con la declaración de esas variables. ¿Seguro que no eres capaz de presentar un ejemplo un poco más pequeño que sea capaz de reproducir el problema del que hablas?

Comment: En todo momento estás mencionando que hay errores en la declaración de esas variables, pero no estás diciendo _cuál es el error_. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta (y no agregues ruido): lee [ask] y también haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.